# How to keep a yoshon kitchen

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, yashan-chadash

[Yoshon](http://cor.ca/view/499/yoshon_frequently_asked_quetions.html) refers, very roughly, to grain products that have grown through at least one Pesach. Some have the stringency to eat only yoshon grains.

How does one go about identifying yoshon flour and other products to use in one's kitchen? I have seen different types of advice [here](http://www.star-k.org/articles/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/YoshonQuick_2015.pdf) and [here](http://cor.ca/view/499/yoshon_frequently_asked_quetions.html), from looking at the date or date code on the food, to buying only specific brands or products. In addition, some packaged foods have a heshcher which indicates yoshon status, but this is not particularly common in the U.S. (especially with staples like flour).

In general, what is the easiest and/or most reliable way to identify grain products as yoshon?

Comment: Great question, but isn't it already answered on the site you linked to? What more information are you looking for?

Comment: It's not a stringency btw. It's the dominant position in traditional poskim. Not keeping it is at best a difficult leniency.

Comment: @ShimonbM Yes and no...I guess I'm trying to find out what people actually do/what is convenient/if there are any tricks. Should I clarify?